# Pdo insert multiple rows by number

Tags: php, pdo

I have little problem and i have no idea how to make it work. 
I want to make query that inserts rows by number.
Example:
If posted number is 8 then query adds 8 rows.

Any idea how to do it with pdo?

Comment: Neither do we. Got code, will travel.

Comment: `if(condition == 8) { for $i = 8 < $var && $var=8; $i++ }` ok, it's wrong and I'm lousy with loops, but you get the general idea.

Comment: can you give more detail?

Comment: query should be like this:
$sql = ("INSERT INTO `tickets` ( `id` ,`name` ,`gameid`, `email`, `win`)
VALUES ('', 'name', 'gameid', 'email', 'win')");

Comment: Thanks fred for the loop idea :) got it like this:

for ($x = 0; $x <= 8; $x++) {  QUERY }

Answer (score 0):

SQL

```
INSERT INTO
    foo(bar,baz)
VALUES
    ("val1", "val2"),
    ("val1", "val2"),
    ("val1", "val2"),
    ("val1", "val2"),
    ("val1", "val2"),
    ("val1", "val2"),
    ("val1", "val2"),
    ("val1", "val2")
;
```

PHP

```
//Insert Statement
$sql = 'INSERT INTO foo(bar,baz) VALUES ';

//Values ("val1", "val2"),("val1", "val2"),("val1", "val2"),..
for ($i = 0; $i <= 8; $i++) {
    $sql.= '("val1", "val2"),';
}

//Remove last Comma, and set ";" at the end.
$sql = rtrim($sql, ",") . ';';
```